# Unresolved symbols with boost_asio/example/ssl/client.cpp

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, boost, openssl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [boost::asio ssl linking error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9805013/boostasio-ssl-linking-error)

I am having issues with undefined symbols. My boost installation is fine as I have used it for other projects. I understand that I need OpenSSL installed, So installed it in the following way.

I then ran the following commands with VS2010 command prompt with the extracted OpenSSL source (most recent from openssl site) as the working directory.

```
perl Configure VC-WIN64A no-shared no-idea // I don't trust this.

ms\do_win64a

nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak
nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak install

nmake -f ms\nt.mak
nmake -f ms\nt.mak install
```

The source file is just the boost example. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/ssl/client.cpp

My VS2010 project is setup as follows.

C/C++ > General > Addition Include Directories

```
E:\libraries\boost_1_49_0   //as used in past projects 
E:\usr\local\ssl\include    //just installed
```

Linker > General > Addition Library Directories

```
E:\libraries\boost_1_49_0\stage\lib
E:\usr\local\ssl\lib
```

Linker > Input > Addition Directories

```
libeay32.lib
```

I thought that it might must have been boost tripping out. So I tried an SSL [crypto](http://www.askyb.com/cpp/using-openssl-cryptography-blowfish-des-rc2-rc4/) example and that had undefined symbols.

Errors in a [text file](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/15586644/boostssltcpconnectionerrors.txt)

OS is Windows 7 64Bit

Comment: What is the error?  Or rather, what are the undefined symbols the compiler and linker are complaining about?

Comment: For SSL you need `ssleay32.lib` as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys. 

I tried that it still has the same issue. On the crypto example any call or type of object from that library is classed as an undefined symbol. The boost examples had like 50-60 errors. I will put them in to a txt file and paste a dropbox link in the main question when I am on the machine, should be about 30-60 mins. - My worry is that the lib has been build incorrectly.

Comment: here is the error file from VS console https://dl.dropbox.com/u/15586644/boostssltcpconnectionerrors.txt

Comment: Even if it is similar to that question, that one is unanswered and dead.

Comment: The documentation for OpenSSL says that if you have this issue that you should use no-asm flag i.e. "perl Configure VC-WIN64A -no-asm", however that results in a failure when doing the ms\do_win64 command http://i.imgur.com/cqohe.png result of do_win64 > http://i.imgur.com/dFSth.png

Comment: I have a feeling I was building a 32 bit program with 64 bit libs. When I changed it to 64 bit compilation in VS it built!

Comment: ********************************************************************THIS IS NOT AN EXACT DUPLICATE AT ALL!! I AM ASKING ABOUT BUILDING OPENSSL SOURCE AND THE OTHER THREAD IS USING A PRE-BUILT VERSION OF OPENSSL.. THEY JUST HAVE UNRESOLVED SYMBOLS. THE SOLUTION IS  DIFFERENT!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to build a 32bit program with the 64 bit libs.

I changed the following from above to build the 64 bit version

perl Configure VC-WIN64A no-asm --prefix=\Dir\for\64\bit\ssl -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE

ms\do_win64a.bat

then nmake as normal